# How to change python version in anaconda spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am using 3.6 Python version in anaconda spyder on my mac. But I want to change it to Python 2.7.

Can any one tell me how to do that?

Comment: Accept the answer whichever is applicable to you. Because it will help the reader for quick review.

Answer (score 54):

You can open the preferences (multiple options):

- keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- `Tools` -> `Preferences`

And depending on the Spyder version you can change the interpreter in the `Python interpreter` section (Spyder 3.x):

[image]

or in the advanced `Console` section (Spyder 2.x):

[image]

Comment: It worked. I needed to install spyder-kernels also via pip.

Answer (score 25):

First, you have to run below codes in `Anaconda prompt`,

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7  #for version 2.7
activate py27

conda create -n py36 python=3.6  #for version 3.6
activate py36
```

Then, you have to open `Anaconda navigator` and,
[image]
The button might say "install" instead of Launch. After the installation, which takes a few moments, It will be ready to launch.

Thank you, @cloudscomputes and @Francisco Camargo.

Comment: When I install Spyder in this way from my Python2 environment, my Python version gets overwritten with 3.6

Answer (score 12):

If you want to keep python 3, you can follow [these directions](http://stuarteberg.github.io/conda-docs/py2or3.html#create-a-python-2-7-environment) to create a python 2.7 environment, called py27.

Then you just need to activate py27:

```
$ conda activate py27
```

Then you can install spyder on this environment, e.g.:

```
$ conda install spyder
```

Then you can start spyder from the command line or navigate to 2.7 version of spyder.exe below the envs directory (e.g. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py27\Scripts)

Comment: This is not fully for this question, but it's a good info. Still working with Spyder 3.2+ ?

Comment: On 6/28/2022, I am trying to follow this advice.  I left my PC on overnight while it was solving environment in response to "conda install spyder".  I already have spyder installed to work with py10. I closed the Anaconda Prompt and am trying now to do it in a new Anaconda Prompt.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can launch the correct version of Spyder by launching from [Ananconda's Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHxhI.png). From the dropdown, switch to your desired environment and then press the launch Spyder button. You should be able to check the results [right away.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnkOQ.png)

Answer (score 4):

In Preferences, select Python Interpreter

Under Python Interpreter, change from "Default" to "Use the following Python interpreter"

The path there should be the default Python executable. Find your Python 2.7 executable and use that.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using anaconda to go into python environment
you should have build up different environment for different python version

The following scripts may help you build up a new environment(running in anaconda prompt)

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7  #for version 2.7
activate py27

conda create -n py36 python=3.6  #for version 3.6
activate py36

you may leave the environment back to your global env by typing
deactivate py27 
or 
deactivate py36
```

and then you can either switch to different environment using your anaconda UI with 
@Francisco Camargo 's answer

or you can stick to anaconda prompt using 
@Dan 's answer

Answer (score 4):

1. Set python3 as a main version in the terminal:
   ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
2. Install pip3:
   apt-get install python3-pip
3. Update spyder:
   pip install -U spyder

Enjoy

Answer (score -2):

In Anaconda, click on "Environments", scroll down to the software package(s) you need to update, and click on the update arrow.

[image: Anaconda software package updates]

Comment: That's to update Python, it's not really the same as using a different version while also keeping the current one.