# sklearn 19.0 installed but spyder still uses 17.1

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-learn, spyder

I have sklearn 0.19 installed on my computer thanks to

```
> conda install scikit-learn=0.19
```

and the terminal says

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/pierre/anaconda3:
...
```

but when I do this in Spyder:

```
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

it still shows

`The scikit-learn version is 0.17.1.`

What should I do to make Spyder use the correct version of `sklearn`?

#### More informations:

I have Python 2.7 installed in Spyder.

I don't see the interpreter icon when I go in "Tools":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using another Python interpreter in Spyder, one which has an old scikit-learn version installed.

The easiest solution is to use the Spyder in the environment where you also have the new `scikit-learn` version. Check if it's installed using:

```
$ conda install spyder
```

Then start the `spyder` from that environment.

---

Alternatively you could also set the interpreter of your Spyder to the environment where you have the new `scikit-learn`:

To change the interpreter used by Spyder (partially based on [this post on "How to change python version in anaconda spyder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder)) you need to open the "Tools" -> "Preferences" (or using the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]

and select your Python interpreter in the section "Python interpreter" -> "Use the following interpreter":

[image]

Comment: Actually, it is Python 3.5 but when I change , I have a warning message saying that it's a risk because Spyder is executed with Python 2 and indeed, after that the script does not run