# importing wrong version of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I have installed `tensorflow 1.5.0` on my machine using `conda`.
I created an environment named `py35` with `python 3.5` and installed `tensorflow 1.0.0` in it.

now in `py35` env when I import `tensorflow` in spyder it is importing `1.5.0`, not `1.0.0`.
In terminal it is importing correct version of tensorflow.

this is kind of weird. I am new to this so maybe I am doing a noob mistake somewhere. if anyone can help me with this it would be great.

I am checking verson by: 
`import tensorflow`
`print(tensorflow.__version__)`

Comment: How are you opening `Spyder`? If you are using the default one that comes with anaconda, it probably is set to look at the default interpreter. Try changing the interpreter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I am opening Spyder with anaconda command prompt , by first activating the env then typing `spyder`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga tried changing interpreter also.. no luck.