# Remember a different set of files in Spyder with different conda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda

I have spyder installed for different conda environments. Despite this, when I open any spyder for python 2.X I have the same source files open. The same goes for any spyder for python 3.X.

I would like to have different source files open in spyder per every environment.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To have that you need to create a Spyder project per each conda environment by going to the menu

`Projects > New project...`

and associating a directory with it.

This is because our saves and loads the set of open files in our Editor associated with each project.

*Note*: This will improved in Spyder **4** (to be released in 2019), when we add the possibility to associate pip/conda envs to our projects.

Comment: This works, but it opens the same project on all the spyders?

Comment: Yes, but you can switch projects quite easily by selecting them in the Projects menu.