# By default Spyder is opening with Spyder Python 2.7 while my Anaconda is installed in Python 3.6+

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, spyder

When i open Spyder from the terminal with the command Spyder, it is opening the Spyder Python 3.7 console, however whenever I'm opening .py files with SPyder, it is by default opening with Spyder 2.7.

I've already checked version of the Spyder along with my Anaconda version. Even in my Ubuntu, the python version is 3.7+

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? That will make a difference.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Thanks I know why and how to fix will post in my morning - it's 10pm here

Comment: Sorry, its 19.04.3 LTS in my laptop, where this is happening, and sure. Thanks.

Comment: Umm 19.04 isn't LTS just to let you know. Now I must get sleep

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have a fix. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder Try what is explained in the answer? It'll be slightly different on Linux obvs.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder is using the `python` command as default, which on Linux defaults to python 2.7. To fix this, set the python command to mean python 3 or whichever version you'd like.

Comment: ? Ok then.... Does Spyders settings have a default version option? I'm not familiar with it - I use pycharm