# Getting Spyder to use python 3 and not python 2

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Anaconda distribution for python using spyder environment on MacBook Pro.

When I go to type 'import cobra' I receive 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cobra''

But when I go to command window and enter python3, in command line 'import cobra' it works fine.

I have python2 and python 3 installed, but it seems that spyder is using python2. How can I get Spyder to switch to python 3 please?

Cheers

Stephen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change python version in anaconda spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder)

Comment: This might be helpful too: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/switch-environment/