# How to install Spyder with Python2 in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

Having followed the instructions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder) identical SO question from a couple of years ago, I find the instructions no longer work. I create a Python 2.7 environment in Anaconda, install Spyder (v4 by default) and find that it overwrites my Python install with Python 3.6. (Although [this](https://pypi.org/project/spyder/) seems to imply Spyder v4 should be compatible with Python2...)

If I choose "install specific version" and select an older version of Spyder, say 3.3.0, my Python 2.7 install is unaffected, but now Spyder fails to launch with the following error: `qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found`.

When I check `qtpy` it's installed with the latest version (1.9.0). I'm guessing this needs to be rolled back, but to what version I don't know. I thought managing these dependencies was what Anaconda was for!

So, does anyone know how I can install Spyder in a Python 2.7 environment in Anaconda?

Comment: _I create a Python 2.7 environment in Anaconda, install Spyder (v4 by default) and find that it overwrites my Python install with Python 3.6._ Can you share the command(s) you used? I just tried to create an environment with `conda create -n test-env python=2 spyder`, and that got me the correct Python version.

Comment: Thank you @AMC, I was just using the Anaconda GUI, but running your command in the terminal does the trick

Comment: You should use the command line tool more, it's quite simple!