# Issues importing pandas and matplotlib in anaconda spyder

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pip, python-import

I tried installing pandas and matplotlib using the pip-command in Anaconda prompt 
`pip install matplotlib` and it gave me the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-p
ackages (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\
lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\pr
ogramdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib
\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site
-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-
packages (from matplotlib) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-p
ackages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (45.2.0.post20200210)
```

And when trying to import in Spyder, it says no module found.
What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spyder is using a different environment for Python. Launch spyder from inside the environment in which you have installed the packages.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Please edit your question so that the stacktrace / error trace is clearly visible.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your spyder points to your anaconda environment. Currently it is not pointing to your anaconda env that is the reason you are getting this error.

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: You can take help from here --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder