# Cannot import ffn after installing anaconda

Tags: python-3.x

I recently installed Anaconda spyder 2020 version, resulting in Python 3.7.6 being installed.

I previously had ffn installed and working.

Now when I run code that tries to import ffn, it comes up with Module not found - No module named 'ffn'.

However, when I issue pip freeze at the console, I can see ffn == 0.3.3

Can anybody shed any light on why I have having problems importing ffn?

Comment: Probably you are using the anaconda version of python.What is appeared right after running the python shell without any argument ? If it's anaconda then either you should find and use your old python binary or install ffn again this time with anaconda.

Comment: Thanks Parsa, When I enter the python without any arguments, it shows up Python 3.5.3 | Anaconda -- which is the pervious version. When it go into Anaconda Spyder, it shows Python 3.7.6. I think I stuffed something up

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder) might help you

Answer (score 0):

If you install anaconda it will automatically install its own version of python with a specific directory for `site-packages` so either you need to find and use your old python binary or install `ffn` again this time with the newly installed anaconda since just syncing the two `site-packages` directories won't work because minor releases of python (e.g 3.7 and 3.5 ) aren't necessarily compatible.

Comment: I like to use the option of reinstalling ffn again, this time against the newly installed anaconda. Is it a simple case of going to the new directory and punching in pip install ffn

Comment: @Jim In my experience using anaconda for some packages is easier than pip but for most packages pip is more handy. It's good to stick with just one of them since if you use both and install each package in them separately you will end up doing much parallel work with maybe gigabytes of excessive downloads.