# How to update python in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am using spyder to run python. But the version of python is 3.8. How can I update it to the latest python in spyder. There are many answers available in internet how to update python in spyder if you are using anaconda distribution. But I am not using anaconda. How can we directly update it from spyder?

Comment: you can download a new version of python from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and change the default python interpreter in Spyder via ```Preferences -> Python interpreter```

Comment: If you are using Anaconda Spyder, you can update your Python to a new version through the anaconda command prompt:  `conda install python=3.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Spyder installation guide:
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html

You should download the latest installer from their website to update Spyder if you are not using conda for management.

Edit: I misunderstood, if you want to change which Python version you want to use in Spyder, you can follow these instructions:
[How to change python version in anaconda spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder)

So in other words, first install the version of Python you want to use from the Python web page, then change Spyder to use that new interpreter as per the above instructions.

Comment: they aren't trying to update Spyder, they're trying to update python