# Failed building wheel for backports-zoneinfo

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, conda, python-wheel

***EDIT***

I tried [clearing my pip cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762308/11357695) due to the error line `Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)` (maybe the cached version is broken/old and incompatible with other packages) - but this made no difference other than removing that line

***CONTEXT***

I've been having dependency issues after installing `Python 3.9` (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320554/import-errors-after-updating-spyder-and-python?noredirect=1#comment134584293_76320554) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314158/spyder-kernels-anaconda-and-python-3-9/76320534?noredirect=1#comment134585043_76320534)).  The issues in the linked posts have been fixed, but I am uninstalling and re-installing my `pip`-installed packages to make sure they are compatible with my new python version.  One of the packages I am trying to do this with is `backports-zoneinfo`.  I am aware I [don't really need this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72796492/11357695), but I was going to keep it anyway in case I write something needing compatibility with older python versions.

***ISSUE:***

I have uninstalled `backports-zoneinfo`, and then tried to reinstall it, but get the error message at the bottom of this post.  I then installed [build tools 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/?fbclid=IwAR2CjL1xcjVN8PCHAszkPfVFix-1Iosqn_wbvp9Ij8whDsQyTKDNe-66nfs) as per the error message and tried to re-install `backports-zoneinfo` again, but got the same error.  Please can someone help me to diagnose and fix the issue?

***Uninstall message:***

```
C:\Users\u03132tk>pip uninstall backports-zoneinfo
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umexpr (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umexpr (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
Found existing installation: backports.zoneinfo 0.2.1
Uninstalling backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.dist-info\*
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backports\*
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backports\functools_lru_cache.py
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backports\tempfile.py
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backports\weakref.py
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1
```

***Reinstall error***

```
C:\Users\u03132tk>pip install backports-zoneinfo
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umexpr (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umexpr (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
Collecting backports-zoneinfo
  Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: backports-zoneinfo
  Building wheel for backports-zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for backports-zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      C:\Users\u03132tk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0o6uoggk\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports
      copying src\backports\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      copying src\backports\zoneinfo\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      copying src\backports\zoneinfo\_tzpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      copying src\backports\zoneinfo\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      copying src\backports\zoneinfo\_zoneinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      copying src\backports\zoneinfo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src\backports.zoneinfo.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\backports.zoneinfo.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\backports.zoneinfo.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\backports.zoneinfo.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\backports.zoneinfo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src\backports.zoneinfo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\backports\zoneinfo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      copying src\backports\zoneinfo\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\backports\zoneinfo
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports-zoneinfo
Failed to build backports-zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports-zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umexpr (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umexpr (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umexpr (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -iopython (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

Comment: You need a compiler that is correctly set up `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to use `import zoneinfo` instead of `import backports.zoneinfo` without any further `pip install`

Comment: If you do need `backports.zoneinfo`, then you could also do `conda install -c conda-forge backpports.zoneinfo`

Comment: Hi FlyingTeller thanks for the help!  How would I set the compiler up, beyond simply downloading the build tools in the link?  I've never actually used it, I was just hoping to get back to the set of programs I had before everything broke, one of which was backports.zoneinfo - this was pip managed, would I be ok to install with conda having uninstalled the pip version?

Comment: You should be fine to `conda install` after `pip uninstall`. Have you tried switching to `import zoneinfo` first though? Since python 3.9. there is a pre-installed stdlib module `zoneinfo` that should have the same functionality as the `backports.zoneinfo` one

Comment: Yes that works perfectly - thanks!  I think I will just stick with this and then if I need to make something for an earlier version I can install with conda.  Can I clarify if I should be doing anything further with the compiler?

Comment: For now, you don't need it, but downloading and installing the build tools should be enough for future python packages. Whenever you need a package though, I would always check if you can install it with conda. Makes your life easier

Comment: Definitely will do in future - last few days has been very educational.  If you copy paste the first couple of comments when you get time I can accept as an answer - many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually fix this specific error, you would need a working compiler on your windows machine:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

For that you would need to follow the link, download and install the build tools and try again.

this particular `pip` package does not have a whl file for python3.9 and at the same time has a source distribution that has parts written in C/C++. Therefore `pip` now needs to call a compiler to build the source distribution for your machine.

To avoid this, you have a few options though:

1. Instead of `pip`, you could try installing the same package using `conda install -c conda-forge backports.zoneinfo`
2. Since `zoneinfo` has become part of the stdlib, you can also try replacing your `import backports.zoneinfo` to `import zoneinfo`. With this method, you would need no further installation.